# How can i change the output of posts_nav_link();

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives, navigation

I would like to change the output of posts_nav_link(); ( Or be pointed in a new direction, that's fine by me ) 
What i want to do is show < Previous      archivepage| Next archivepage > even if there is no previous or next page, currently it removed whichever link isn't in use, i would like it to still show the text < previous, so i can style it in a lighter grey tone ( disabled )
Hope this makes sense.

I've tried creating custom page nav for my archive pages but it wont work..

```
 <h1>custom loop</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">

 <?php 
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 $args = array(
     'post_type'=>'post', // Your post type name
     'posts_per_page' => 6,
     'paged' => $paged,
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

              // YOUR CODE
 the_id();
 echo '<br/>';
     endwhile;
 ?>
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
```

Desired output:

```
< Previous archivepage | Next archivepage >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts_nav_link()` just outputs `get_previous_posts_link()` and `get_next_posts_link()` with a separator between them. The helpful thing is does is handle the visibility of the separator depending on whether both pages exist. Since you always want to show something on either side, you don't need it. What you can do is output the next and previous links manually, but with a check to see of there is a link. If there isn't you can output a span instead.

That would look like this:

```
if ( get_previous_posts_link() ){
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
} else {
    echo '<span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span>';
}

echo '|';

if ( get_next_posts_link() ){
    next_posts_link( 'Next' );
} else {
    echo '<span aria-hidden="true">Next</span>';
}
```

Now you can style `<span>` as the inactive link.

Note that I've used `aria-hidden="true"` to tell screen readers to ignore the text of the inactive 'links' as an accessibility featured.

Comment: thanks, you forgot 2 ; after the span statements i've edited and tested, works out of the box. Will accept

Answer (score 0):

The [`posts_nav_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link) function accepts 3 arguments.

```
<?php posts_nav_link( $sep, $prelabel, $nextlabel ); ?>
```

You can set the `$sep` to `'|'` and change the next and previous labels. There's no need to output back and forth navigation separately.

Comment: will it work,if there is no previous or next page?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't show the links if there is no posts. Check the `if ( get_previous_posts_link() ){ ... }` part. But I'm not sure if my answer acts the same way, you can paste the code and simply try it.